# How to escape a - in a table name in mysqldump

Tags: mysql

If I want to exclude a table in a schema which contains a minus `-`, how do I escape that in mysqldump? Or do I not need to?

```
mysqldump --ignore-table=foo-bar.tl_log
```

does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 5.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table)

Try following:

> mysqldump --ignore-table=database.table1

Comment: I know the basic syntax, my database contains a hypen

Answer (score 2):

No special escaping is needed:

```
me@orange ~$ mysqldump foo-bar
-- MySQL dump 10.15  Distrib 10.0.24-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: foo-bar
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.0.24-MariaDB-7

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `baz`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `baz`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `baz` (
  `baz` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `baz`
--

LOCK TABLES `baz` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `baz` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `baz` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-04-22 18:37:55



me@orange ~$ mysqldump foo-bar --ignore-table=foo-bar.baz
-- MySQL dump 10.15  Distrib 10.0.24-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: foo-bar
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.0.24-MariaDB-7

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-04-22 18:38:07
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally escape a hyphen <kbd>-</kbd> with quotes so I would expect the following to work:

```
mysqldump --ignore-table='foo-bar.tl_log'
```

Comment: If this is run from a shell, the shell will probably strip a layer of quotes ,so you would probably need `mysqldump --ignore-table='"foo-bar".tl_log'`